# Flexible Like in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have this code. But I can not get it anything.

```
       SMain_EW = RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
       Dim MyCheck
       If SMain_EW Like "*" & Me.Text0 & "*" = True Then
           MsgBox "1"
       End If
```

Edited:************************
I edited as bellow:

```
        Do Until RS.EOF
           SMainEW = RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
           ST_EW_1 = RS.Fields("T_EW_1").Value
           If SMainEW Like "*" & Me.Text0 & "*" Then
               strItem1 = "*" & RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
               strItem2 = RS.Fields("T_EW_1").Value
           ElseIf ST_EW_1 Like "*" & Me.Text0 & "*" Then
               strItem2 = "*" & RS.Fields("T_EW_1").Value
               strItem1 = RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
           Else
               strItem2 = RS.Fields("T_EW_1").Value
               strItem1 = RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
           End If
            strItem = strItem1 & ";" _
            & strItem2
            Me.List122.AddItem strItem
           RS.MoveNext
        Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "= True" portion, it's redundant.  It should just read:

```
   SMain_EW = RS.Fields("Main_EW").Value
   Dim MyCheck
   If SMain_EW Like "*" & Me.Text0 & "*" Then
       MsgBox "1"
   End If
```

Comment: Thank you. When I type "a" or "b" in Text0, it is true but when I type "c" or "s" or "y", it is wrong. This code undrestand, for example, "abandon" but dose not undrestand "accurate". Why?

Comment: Try stepping through the code (put a code break on the "SMain_EW =" line) and then hover your mouse over each variable to see what Access thinks the variable is equal to.  You can also use the Immediate window to do this as well.  Usually, what you think a variable is equal to and what Access thinks the variable is equal to are two different things, and you can figure out where the discrepancy is.

Comment: I am testing my program.

Comment: I edit my code such as Edited:****. I got true answer.